# How raw type works in Java?

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I'm learning about generics and I have a misunderstanding.

For example I have this simple code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1);
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass().getName()); 
        int value = (Integer) list.get(0);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why should I cast the `list.get(0)` to `Integer` because this statement `System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass().getName());` has this result `java.lang.Integer`?

If I use this statement `int value = list.get(0);` I get this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to int`... and I really don't understand, is `list.get(0)` an `Object` or an `Integer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list.get(0).getClass().getName()` will access an element in the List, and find out *at runtime* that it's indeed an integer. It could be anything else, though.

What the compiler knows *at compile time* is that your `list` contains items of type `Object`, see the signature of `List.get(int)`. So it can't prove that `int value = list.get(0)` would always be correct. You have to explicitly cast.

The whole generics thing in Java is compile-time only. It's a way to tell the compiler how to limit type-parametrized classes only to particular types, and thus guarantee *at compile time* that operations on them are indeed correct. That is, the compiler won't allow you to put a `String` into a `List<Integer>`.

In runtime, the type parametrization information is *erased*. The JVM operates on by relying on the compiler having done the job of generating correct code. There's nothing at runtime that allows the JVM to know what type the content of a `List` is; `ArrayList` has a single implementation for any class parameters. (This is unlike C# or C++.)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` of raw type. It acts like an `ArrayList<Object>`. You can add all sub-types of object to it (and this is almost all).

So, if you take an object back from list, then it is a `Object` - at compile-time you cant know if it a `Integer` or `String`.

You dont need the cast when use a `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Edit:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(1); // an int
        list.add("Test"); // an String
        list.add(new Object()); // and empty

        var rnd = RandomUtils.random(list.size());

        for (Object value : list)      
           System.out.println(value.getClass().getName()); 


       list.get(rnd) // so, what is the type of the object?
       // the compiler cannot know it (compile-time), you need to run the program and check it (runtime)

    }
}
```

Edit2:
See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: There is actually a *big* difference between `ArrayList` and `ArrayList<Object>`. They are not the same, precisely because raw types are a special case.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use raw type (like `ArrayList` without any generic type) Java assumes that the type of elements in that list is `Object`. So `list.get(0)` will return reference of type `Object`. And because of that you need to cast.

Object returned by `list.get(0)` is of type `Integer` but reference to it is of type `Object` and that's why compiler complaint because you want to assign reference of type `Object` to a variable of primitive type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Plain ArrayList means `ArrayList<?>`, which means an ArrayList containing objects of unspecifed type.   Since all objects derive from Object, the best you can say about those objects is that they're Objects.

The fact that, at run time a particular Object might turn out to be an Integer (as well) does not void the problem that at compilation time the object type is not known.

Consider:

```
list.add(1);
list.add("two");
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i).getClass().getName());
```

Now what is the type of list.get(i) ?

My question would be: why are you using raw types?